# How to delete files that has a specific word on their name in php

Tags: php

In my directory i have these files:

JBBsongs.html, JBB.php, ArrangeJBB.html, Follow.html and follow.php

I know I can delete a specific file using `unlink`

```
<?php

unlink('test.html');
?>
```

But how can I delete specific files that contains "JBB" on their names?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can loop through your directory using `scandir`and check for files containing `JBB` using `strpos` and then `unlink` it.

```
    $dir="./";
    $files=scandir($dir);
    if(is_array($files)){
        foreach($files as $file){
            if(is_file($dir.$file) && strpos($file,"JBB")!==false){
                unlink($dir.$file);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Never thought of this. thank You!

Answer (score 2):

Use [strstr ()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php) function.

Assuming you already have your file names in an array, you can do something like

```
<?php
$files = Array ('JBBsongs.html', 'JBB.php', 'ArrangeJBB.html', 'Follow.html', 'follow.php');

foreach ($files as $file)
{
    if (strstr ($file, "JBB"))
    {
        unlink('test.html');
    }
}
?>
```

`strstr` returns `false` if the *needle* (the searched string) is not present in the first string. In this way only the desired files will be unlinked.

Answer (score 1):

you can loop among all the files in a folder using readdir or scandir.
once you have the filename you can check strpos of JBB. if the strpos value is equal to or greater than 0. then you can call the unlink function on the filename. This will delete the file